# Software development “todo” (issue) tracker hosted locally

Tags: gratis, self-hosted, issue-tracker, todo

I work as a code developer for an enterprise. Normally, I when the client asks for a new feature or a bugfix, I write it down on a piece of paper, and then I copy it in an Excel file. When the task is finished, I write down the version of the software in which the feature was released. The problem is that this workflow is error prone.

For software version control I always use Git.

I am looking for a tool that would enable me to better keep track of my "todos", with a priority, expected date, software version in which it is finally implemented, etc. I looked around the internet, but I didn't find what I am looking for, as most of the tools I see are not-free or hosted in external servers.

I really need something simple, but with these minimal features:

- Free (open source would be nice)
- Locally hosted
- Integrated with Git if possible, to better track the changes in the code

What is not needed:

- Multi-user
- Cloud

Comment: Would "something like Github but hosted locally" fit your needs (thinking of the "issues" part here)? If so, [Gogs](https://gogs.io/) or its fork [Gitea](https://gitea.io/) might be worth a look. Install is easy (it's just a single binary and stays within its directory), and it integrates with Git. If you need it more sophisticated, [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/) can be very much customized including ticket priorities and dependencies – but that'd be a bigger install. Both can be used locally and from remote, running on *your* hardware (no cloud dependency).

Answer (score 2):

You could always use git itself!

- Have a directory called bugs and one called feature_requests,
- when you get a request create a new bug or feature request as a markdown or rst file, yo*u could use a sequential numbering or more complex* and then check it in,
- when it is finished add the details to the file including which release it is due in and check in again
- and then after the release rename it to a Done sub-folder.

I am sure that you could knock up a template and some quick query tools, grep is great for this sort of thing.

- Free
- Integrated with git
- Locally hosted
- Simple
- No additional hardware
- BUT No build in reporting tools.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/).

The issue tracker is superb. It also includes a Kanban-Board, but I don't know if this is included in the free edition.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the mylin plugin in eclipse. I don't know it very well, but I'm sure it's locally hosted, allows for todos (and store the context, ie views and open documents , for each of them) . I don't remember if it has a specific function for the bugfix version, but you can add a note with the commit number for example

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found Kamban http://topols.io/. Offline & Lightweigt. I like it. Unfortunatly no Git integration.

Comment: On this SE it's customary to explain why you recommend a software and not just provide a link to it.